# I'm new to coding, cant figure out how to translate span class to css

Tags: html, css

I've taken the tutorial 3 or 4 times and still am having trouble identifying what I need to do to make the css what its supposed to be in the given instructions.

I'm using codepen and the instructions are provided in the html, but I am having a difficult time translating the HTML when it comes to span in css.

Here is the link to the project with what I have completed so far (basically nothing after the the first class: https://codepen.io/tvanpelt/pen/LodgKd

```
<h3 id='id1'>Red text header!</h3>
 <p class="class1">This paragraph should have a black background and yellow text</p>
 <span class="class1">Black background and white text.</span>
 <span>Blue background and white text.</span>
 </div>
  <div>
 <h3>Red text header with Grey background!</h3>
  <p>Green text with white background color</p>
  <p id="id2">Green text, white background color</p>
 </div>
```

I would like a better understand how to use the same class name as it appears in html to convert into css to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this a number of ways. It seems like the point of the question was to target individual elements in a way that, to me at least, seems a little bit convoluted. The main take away being that you can combine selectors to target more specific elements. I've pasted my solution below.

Cheers

```
#id1 {
  color:red;
  background-color: white;

}

p.class1{
  color: yellow;
}

.class1 {

  background-color: black

}

span {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

div h3 {
  color: red;
  background-color: grey;
}

p{
  color: green;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, my problem was being able to target specific areas within that lesson, and how to use those selectors to define those specific areas. Thank you for showing me how specific you can be.

Answer (score 0):

I think what it is trying to teach you is how to combine selectors in order to increase specificity. span is an HTML element, so the css selector is simply span. Then a span with class 1 is span.class1. The style that is applied to each element is the one with the highest specificity (a class is more specific than an element, an ID is more specific than a class etc.)

I wrote out the css for part of your codepen below, as an example, hopefully it sets you on the right track.

```
span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
span.class1 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp for a reference of selectors, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity for more information on specificity.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference guides. These will help a lot!

Comment: Yes, my problem was being able to target specific areas within that lesson, and how to use those selectors to define those specific areas. Thank you.